# ubuntu16.04 lts build android5.0 Error

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, ubuntu-16.04

When I build android5.0 on ubuntu16.04 I get the following errors:

> external/libcxx/include/atomic:539:2: error: #error  is not implemented
>   art/runtime/atomic.h:155:5: error: 'atomic_thread_fence' is not a member of 'std'
>   art/runtime/atomic.h:155:30: error: 'memory_order_acquire' is not a member of 'std'
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:50:44: error: 'art::mirror::Class* art::CheckClassInitializedForObjectAlloc(art::mirror::Class*, art::Thread*, bool*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:146:33: error: 'art::mirror::ArtField* art::FindFieldFast(uint32_t, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, art::FindFieldType, size_t)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:152:34: error: 'art::mirror::ArtMethod* art::FindMethodFast(uint32_t, art::mirror::Object*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, bool, art::InvokeType)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:158:30: error: 'art::mirror::Class* art::ResolveVerifyAndClinit(uint32_t, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool, bool)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:166:31: error: 'art::mirror::String* art::ResolveStringFromCode(art::mirror::ArtMethod*, uint32_t)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:171:20: error: 'void art::UnlockJniSynchronizedMethod(jobject, art::Thread*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   art/runtime/entrypoints/entrypoint_utils.h:177:20: error: 'void art::CheckSuspend(art::Thread*)' declared 'static' but never defined [-Werror=unused-function]
>   cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

Why does it appear?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by modifying `$ANDROID_REPO/art/build/Android.common_build.mk`:

```
-#ART_HOST_CLANG := false
-#ifneq ($(WITHOUT_HOST_CLANG),true)
 - # By default, host builds use clang for better warnings.
 ART_HOST_CLANG := true
-#endif
```

to make sure `ART_HOST_CLANG = true`. Then, I created the following symlink:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/ld.gold $ANDROID_REPO/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/(glibc version)/x86_64-linux/bin/ld
```

Reference: [xda-developers forum: how to setup Ubuntu 16.04](http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-how-to-setup-ubuntu-16-04-lts-t3363669/page2)